# Nothing in Bin folder after Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to build multiple different cpp file(s) into their own respective executables, using their default filenames.

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe")

project(myproj CXX)

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

function(build_third_party_lib dir_name target_name)
    add_subdirectory(./${dir_name} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
    if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "MSVC")
        # For Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler (MSVC)
        target_compile_options(${target_name} PRIVATE /w)
    elseif(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "GNU|Clang")
        # For GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) or Clang
        target_compile_options(${target_name} PRIVATE -w)
    endif()
endfunction()


include_directories(./)
build_third_party_lib(fmt fmt)

file(GLOB APP_SOURCES src/*.cpp)
foreach(SOURCE_PATH ${APP_SOURCES})
    get_filename_component(EXECUTABLE_NAME ${SOURCE_PATH} NAME_WE)
    add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SOURCE_PATH})
endforeach(SOURCE_PATH ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

I run this with the following command: `cmake . -G "MinGW Makefiles"` and a bin and lib folder are generated. No errors appear. But, the directories are empty.

What am I missing?

Comment: CMake "merely" prepares the build/project files. To actually start building, you can call mingw32-make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project files are now available,but the project has not been built yet.To build it, use this command:

```
cmake --build /pathTo/build --config Debug --target MyApp
```

The --build option points to the build directory used by the CMake project generation step. For multi configuration generators.

The --config option specifies which configuration to build, whereas single configuration generators will ignore the --config option and rely instead on information provided when the CMake project generation step was performed.

The --target option can be used to tell the build tool what to build, or if omitted, the default target will be built

Comment: `Running

   'nmake' '-?'

  failed with:

   The system cannot find the file specified`